# Web Server Apache Installation Database Server MYSQL Installation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache

I am setup up a WordPress based website by trying to implement 2 Web Server in front with 1 Database Server.

Most of the information show how to install LAMP. 
PHP should be install into Web Server or Database Server?

Anyone found any resources how to setup Web Server and Database Separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont understand the Problem?

**2 Webserver**

You need to install a Webserver (Apache, Nginx etc.) according to the manual on 2 Server.

**Database Server**

You need to install a Database (MSSQL,MYSQL,PSQL) according to the manual on the third Server. Make sure to set a Firewall Rule for the Database, so both webserver can reach it. Also make sure, you allow Remote Access in the Database Configuration.

**Programm Code**

From Server Side (PHP, ASP.NET) you connect via IP or Domain instead of `localhost` to the Database Server.

**Tutorial**

Take a look into this. It is not that what you want. But it shows how to install MySQL with Remote Access and install Apache.

http://blog.vinhkhoa.com/article/Set-up-a-Railo-Apache-MySQL-host-on-Ubuntu-Part-2-install-MySQL-and-enable-remote-access

Comment: If you do not understand why do you answer?

Comment: @christian Thanks for replying. But would like to know where should I install the PHP to?? Web Server or Database ServeR?

Comment: @CarsonLee PHP ist a Part of the Webserver, so it make no sense to install it on the database server ;)

Comment: @tntu we in germany call this "Sarkasmus". I realy think, there a thousands of tutorials outside about webservers, databases, load balancer etc. pp.

Comment: @ChristianGollhardt thanks so much!! Actually I m quite news to this area. Thanks for helping me out =D.

Comment: This with is for answers to questions about problems not how to do things one has no clue about. People should show at least the minimum effort of reasearch and some attempts abefore asking for help.